# riak / python: unable to run a store() command

Tags: python, riak

Attempting to follow the tutorial [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/taste-of-riak/python/).

After doing basic CRUD stuff, the tutorial [has you edit the `app.config` file](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/taste-of-riak/querying/) to use the LevelDB Backend for 2i, which in my case meant updating line 83 of `/usr/local/Cellar/riak/1.4.2/etc/app.config` from

```
            {storage_backend, riak_kv_bitcask_backend},
```

to

```
            {storage_backend, riak_kv_eleveldb_backend},
```

and then restarting riak.

I had thus far been running riak on port 8098, and their tutorial [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/taste-of-riak/querying-python/) references port 10017 instead:

```
# Starting Client
client = riak.RiakClient(pb_port=10017, protocol='pbc')

# Creating Buckets
customer_bucket = client.bucket('Customers')
order_bucket = client.bucket('Orders')
order_summary_bucket = client.bucket('OrderSummaries')


# Storing Data
cr = customer_bucket.new(str(customer['customer_id']),
                         data=customer)
cr.store()
```

if I try to run the code as written, I get this:

```
 File "r.py", line 104, in <module>
    cr.store()
  File ".../riak/riak-python-client-master/riak/riak_object.py", line 281, in store
    timeout=timeout)
  File ".../riak/client/transport.py", line 127, in wrapper
    return self._with_retries(pool, thunk)
  File ".../riak/client/transport.py", line 82, in _with_retries
    raise e.args[0]
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

suggesting that, clearly, the Riak client is not running on port 10017.

However, when I change it to port 8098

```
client = riak.RiakClient(pb_port=8098, protocol='pbc')
```

the application just freezes on the `cr.store()` line. Is there some thing where the eleveldb backend is expecting to run on a port other than default?

Answer (score 1):

never mind, 8098 is the http port, when I changed it to port 8087, the default port, it works fine

Comment: Author here, I'll put a note in there to watch for this. We try to make the tutorial usable to both devrel and package installed users, but each method uses different port numbers.